# Javascript array contains only undefined after initialization, not the given values

Tags: javascript, arrays, undefined

I thought I knew how to declare javascript arrays but in this script I am getting an infinite loop of `undefined` elements in the array.

I declare three arrays of numbers, two of which have multiple values and one which has a single value.

I have a switch statement that assigns one of the three arrays to a new variable name `cluster_array`

When I run a `for` loop through `cluster_array`, I get an infinite loop and every element if `undefined`

What am I missing?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ga_west_cluster = new Array(10,11,12,14,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,295,296);

// original bad array
    var ga_east_cluster = new Array(84);
// added an extra (dummy) value and it works fine   
    var ga_east_cluster = new Array(1,84);
    var sc_cluster      = new Array(93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103);
</script>
```

Here is the `alert` text:

```
var test_message        = "cluster data\n";
    for(var k=0;k<cluster_array.length;k++)
        test_message    += "value: "+cluster_array[k]+"\n";
```

[image: test alert box]

Comment: can you paste your switch statement ?

Comment: @moe it turns out that I was declaring the array the wrong way, per @Pointy's answer

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Don't initialize arrays like that.  Always do this instead:

```
var myarray = [value, value, value, ... ];
```

The "Array()" constructor is terribly designed. The single-argument form, when the argument is a number, is interpreted as a request to "initialize" an array with that many "empty" values.  It's a pointless thing to do, so in general you're much better off using the array constant notation (as in my example above).

It doesn't seem to happen anymore in modern browsers, but I'd swear that there was a time that at least some browsers would actually allocate memory for the single-argument constructor, which was not really useful but dangerous to code that might accidentally pass in a single very large number.

Comment: The `Array` constructor can still be useful. Eg, it can be used to create loops where each value returned is accumulated in an array. So this.. `new Array(4).fill().map((v, i) => i)` will return the array `[0, 1, 2, 3]`

Comment: @Molomby yes that's good advice; this answer is over 6 years old, and that's forever in JavaScript time :)